# CSV reader not getting column values

Tags: python, csv

```
db_path = "./db_file.csv"
db_read = open(db_path, "r") 
for row in db_read:
    g_tag = (row)[1]
```

My code is not accessing the second column as expected. Instead it is returning the second character of the 0th column. Don't get whats going on.

Comment: can you provide the first few lines of your csv file as an example to work with?

Comment: Give your `csv` data, there might be somehting worng with data.

Answer (score 1):

Salah is right, although I'd advise against parsing a csv file directly:

```
In [63]: with open('output.csv', 'r') as f:
    ...:     reader = csv.reader(f)
    ...:     for row in reader:
    ...:         print row
    ...:
['latitude', 'local_time', 'longitude', 'time']
['51.2997804', '20:01:14:334 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00', '1.070336', '1439319674334']
['51.2997889', '20:01:34:428 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00', '1.0703332', '1439319694428']
['51.2997794', '20:01:54:638 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00', '1.0703123', '1439319714638']
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to parse csv files intuitively, otherwise you can just use `row.split(',')` to get values

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to do this:

```
        db_read = open(db_path, 'r')
        db_reader = csv.reader(db_read)
```

Comment: If you are looking to follow best practice, I would very much encourage you to use a context manager (with open('your.csv', 'r') as file: ) this will close the file object for you, its a good habit to get in.